# Page Scraper and DOM manipulator

Tags: c#, web-scraping

This code is a page scraper using HtmlAgilityPack that creates a DOM document upon construction and allows for node manipulation afterward.

HtmlAgilityPack uses XPath Selectors for selecting nodes.

An example use case would look like:

```
var me = new PageScraper("http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62429/quill", Console.WriteLine);
var usernameNode = me.FetchNode("//h2[@class=user-card-name]");
var username = PageScraper.FetchNodeText(usernameNode);
```

This is the `PageScraper` class, the only class in the `Scraper` namespace so far.

The reason I pass in an `Action` is so that I can attach log messages to a Forms list box.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Scraper
{
    public class PageScraper
    {
        private readonly HtmlDocument _document;
        public Action<string> Print { get; set; }
        public PageScraper(string url, Action<string> print)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                throw new Exception("url is empty");
            }
            Print = print;
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Print("downloading page");
            string urlWithoutNewLineCharacters = StripNewLineCharactersAndSpaces(url);
            string html = webClient.DownloadString(urlWithoutNewLineCharacters);
            _document = new HtmlDocument();
            _document.LoadHtml(html);
            Print("loading page");
        }
        public HtmlNodeCollection FetchLinks()
        {
            Print("fetching links");
            return _document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
        }  

        public HtmlNodeCollection FetchNodes(string selector)
        {
            Print("fetching nodes");
            return _document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(selector);
        }

        public HtmlNode FetchNode(string selector)
        {
            Print("fetching node");
            return _document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(selector);
        }

        public static string FetchNodeText(HtmlNode node)
        {
            if (node != null && node.InnerText != null)
            {
                return node.InnerText;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
        public static string FetchNodeHref(HtmlNode node)
        {
            if (node != null && node.Attributes["href"].Value != null)
            {
                return node.Attributes["href"].Value;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
        private static string StripNewLineCharactersAndSpaces(string str)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(str, @"\t|\n|\r| |\s+", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
> {
>     throw new Exception("url is empty");
> }
> ```

Throwing a general `Exception` is mostly bad. If the `url` parameter is `null` you should throw an `ArgumentNullException` and if it is "empty" you should throw an `ArgumentException` like so

```
if (url == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url)); }  
if (url.Length == 0) { throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(url)} is empty", nameof(url)); }
```

---

> ```
> WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
> ```

You should make use of the `var` type here because the assigned type is obvious from the right hand side of the assignment.

---

You don't check if the passed in `Action<string>` is `null`. A general rule of thumb is to check for every public accessible method wether the passed in arguments are null, because it is much better to get an exception early. In this case I would change the `Print` property in a way that it has a backing field instead of beeing autoimplemented. In this way you can use the setter to place the `null` validation. If the value is `null` you need to replace it with a noop action like so

```
private Action<string> _print;
public Action<string> Print
{
    get
    {
        return _print;

    }
    set
    {
        _print = value ?? ((s) => { });
    }
}
```

In addition this will allow you to also have an overloaded constructor which only take the `string url` as a parameter. Adding the suggestion of  [@MarquisBlount](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/83868/marquis-blount) of having an initialization method would then lead to

```
public PageScraper(string url, Action<string> print)
{
    if (url == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url)); }
    if (url.Length == 0) { throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(url)} is empty", nameof(url)); }

    _document = new HtmlDocument();
    Print = print;

    LoadDocument(url);
}

public PageScraper(string url)
    : this(url, null)
{ }

private void LoadDocument(string url)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();

    Print("downloading page");

    string urlWithoutNewLineCharacters = StripNewLineCharactersAndSpaces(url);
    string html = webClient.DownloadString(urlWithoutNewLineCharacters);

    _document.LoadHtml(html);

    Print("loading page");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> Print = print;
> WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
> Print("downloading page");
> string urlWithoutNewLineCharacters = StripNewLineCharactersAndSpaces(url);
> string html = webClient.DownloadString(urlWithoutNewLineCharacters);
> _document = new HtmlDocument();
> _document.LoadHtml(html);
> Print("loading page");
> ```

You are doing too much in your constructor. Consider extracting some of this code into separate method(s) maybe an `intitialize()` method or `buildDocument()` method. The rule for this is know as **Coding at Wrong Level of Abstraction**.

Your method `StripNewLineCharactersAndSpaces` should be called right after the first time it is used not at the end of your class. this is known as **Vertical Separation** This allows reads to quickly ready your code without having to bounce around too much.

I do Like that you have kept your methods really small